# database since different activities in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to access since different activities to an unique database, however when I work with databases I have to create a different database instance since every activity and this produce an unwanted result, how can i manage an unique database since different activities?

Comment: Try a `Singleton` or `Transactions`.

Answer (score 0):

> however when I work with databases I have to create a diferent
>   database instance since every activity and this produce an unwanted
>   result, how can i manage an unique database since diferents
>   activities?

So did you think about [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)? I think your problem is directly designated for an usage of Singleton design pattern. An usage has only benefits(always only one instance, not wasting of memory, clean and human-readable code etc.).

Let's write some code:

```
private static SQLiteOpenHelper instance;

public static SQLiteOpenHelper getInstance(Context c) {
   if (instance == null) {
      instance = new SQLiteOpenHelperImplementation(c);
   }
   return instance;
}
```

I have only good experiences with Singleton.

### Notes:

To improve your work with database i have a few suggestions for you:

- If you have more than one table, i suggest you to create "operation"
  classes which will wrap `CRUD` operations and specific methods for each
  table.
- To improve performance, security and integrity of db always use
  `TRANSACTIONS`. It's very useful and efficient practise
- In concurrent programming, always use synchronized blocks and methods to avoid problems related to access to database and making changes
- Always when work is done, release your cursors and close database